# SQL Server: unable to save the changes after applying the Identity key on table

Tags: sql, sql-server

While I am trying to apply identity column on a table, I can't save the changes;  while trying to save, I'm getting an error shown here:

[image]

Comment: Pretty straightforward error. You need to drop and recreate the table to make this change.

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste error messages into your question *as plain text*. Don't post images of text.

Answer (score 1):

See Options in SQL Server Management Studio

[image]

Comment: Thanks to everyone (@SQLAndOtherstuffGuy AND @ marc_s)it's working now